# How to get a substring with specific format

Tags: java, android

I am creating a program in which I am trying to take the results from a cmd command(netstat -na) and then save the IP's and their ports.

A "netstat -na" result is like this

> TCP  0.0.0.0:123 0.0.0.0:456 LISTENING...

I am using a BufferedReader to read the input stream

```
try{
        String cmd = "netstat -na";
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);            
        BufferedReader inputBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader errorBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

        // Grab the results
        String line;
        while ((line = inputBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line.contains("%s.%s.%s.%s:%s")) {
                Log.i(TAG, "yes");
                String sub = ...
                // what can i do?
            }
        }

        while ((line = errorBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("TAG", line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I thought to check if the line contains a sub-string with this format, but it is not working.
How to check if the line contains a sub-string like this (0.0.0.0:123) and then save it?

Comment: String.contains takes a string, so you could literally check if the string contains 0.0.0.0:123. If you are looking for a specific format then you should look into creating a Regex pattern and passing that in the contains method. Websites like this help: https://regex101.com/

Comment: I am not looking for 0.0.0.0:123, i am looking for a substring with an ip format

Comment: Like I said, then you need regex.

Comment: @SerKleanthis please check out my answer, that should help you out

Comment: @TimKranen thank you mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### REGEX!

You should use regex to match your use case : the following regex will match an ip with the port at the end : `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,6}`.

So now if you consider the whole regex for the whole out pattern, it will be as following :
`^TCP ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,6}) ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,6}) LISTENING\.\.\.$`

What do we have here ? This might sounds quite complicated.

- `[0-9]{1,3}` will match 1 to 3 digits `123` for example
- Then `\.` will match a `.`
- Then this same pattern is repeated four time to match all 4 numbers of an ip address.
- Finally, you have `:` which will match `:` followed by `[0-9]{1,6}` which will match 1 to 6 successive digits.
- Now this whole string is put into parenthesis twice so that we will be able to retrieve it later on. We add `TCP`  at the beginning and `LISTENING.\.\.\` at the end.
- `^` and `$` are anchors to stipulate that the string to match should start and end with this pattern. There shouldn't be any additional character.

Now, how to do this in java ?

```
  private static final String IP_PATTERN_STRING = "([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,6})";
  private static final String NETSTAT_OUTPUT_PATTERN_STRING = "^TCP " + IP_PATTERN_STRING + " " + IP_PATTERN_STRING + " LISTENING\\.\\.\\.$";

  private static final Pattern NETSTAT_OUTPUT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(NETSTAT_OUTPUT_PATTERN_STRING);

  public String extractIpAddress(String netstatOut) {
       Matcher m = NETSTAT_OUTPUT_PATTERN.matcher(netstatOut);
       
       if(m.matches()) 
          // depending on if you want the first or the second ip
          // address of the command, use 1 or 2.
          return m.group(1);
       return null;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to extract all occurrences of the pattern, like:

```
String s = "TCP 0.0.0.0:123 0.0.0.0:456 LISTENING...";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\d\.\d\.\d\.\d:\d{3}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
String sub = "";
while (matcher.find()) {
    sub = matcher.group(0);
    System.out.println(sub);
    // your code here
}
```

the above code prints:

> 0.0.0.0:123  
>   0.0.0.0:456

if there is a possibility of occurrences like this:  
120.2.55.211:124 or 120.2.55.211:12 then change the pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}:\\d{1,3}");
```